# Amazon EC2 T2 instance running out of CPU credits in minutes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a T2.Micro instance running but the instance managed to run out of credits in instants while adding/deleting images from a wordpress website
Currently running wordpress/nginx only, and have no real trafic on the site, mostly for prototyping.
Sharing a graph of credit utilization:
[image]

that gap is, (i think) because i stopped and started the instance

From what i read it should consume 1 credit over each minute running at 100%, so how could it go from 140+ to 30 in <10 minutes ?
Shouldn't it at least last for 110 minutes running at 100% ?
Or was it working at 1100%+ for <10 minutes? (if that is possible ?)

EDIT: First graph is a bit hard to interpret, since the gap is not visible and hard to explain, so im sharing the last 6hour graph in 5 min increment:
[image]

Comment: Are you saying that the instance was stopped during the period shown on the very _left_ of the chart, or was it stopped for a brief period when the chart goes down in the _middle_? (And are you sure?)

Comment: i created the instance recently, so the leftmost is just time before instance creation, the first time it crashed is when the graph sinks for the first time, but i just went to bed and next day was working fine. Today it happened again, so i tried restarting the instance, and that is the gap at the end(right) of the graph, and after the startup of the instance the graph shows at the bottom (im hovering the blue dot in the picture at ~30 credits)

edit: wording

Comment: Logging to the instance and check processes running. Maybe you have something hammering cpu.

Comment: When you say that you "restarted" the instance, did you choose the "Reboot instance" command, or did you choose "Stop instance" and then "Start instance"? Rebooting should not impact the credits. The documentation says _"For T2, the CPU credit balance does not persist between instance stops and starts. If you stop a T2 instance, the instance loses all its accrued credits."_

Comment: i did a reboot, and as that did not suffice i did a stop/start, guess i now know the reason for the sudden drop in credits ‍

Answer (score 0):

The graph is showing **average over a 5-minute period**.

The sharp reduction in the middle is probably where the instance was Stopped and Started. Credits are lost when the instance is stopped, but the graph is showing an average over a 5-minute period so it slowly drops down.

If you changed the 5-minute resolution to something shorter (if possible), you might get a better idea of what is happening. Also, wait a bit longer after an instance is launched so that you can collect more data.

Comment: I have added another graph that better reflects the start and stop after the unresponsiveness. You can see it slightly ticking down, and once its back up credits are all gone and remains unresponsive